# FOR loop to compare user input from a list and run predefined command

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

i'm using .bat to facilitates telnet in my company. it will get user input and if the ip being input by the user matching in the predefined list it will carry some commands and if the user input is not match it will run another set of command below is the problematic command area on my batch; any xtra info needed pls ask for it. thanks in advanced...

```
:portinfo
cls
echo.
echo    ====================
echo    1. Switch VLan Menu:
echo    ====================
echo.
set /p ip=Access Switch IP : 
set /p uname=Uname : 
set /p passwd=Password : 
set /p faint=Interface : Fa0/ 
set /p vlan=Vlan to switch to :
```

*FOR LOOP STARTS HERE*

```
for %ip% in ('10.195.30.5' '10.195.102.42' '10.195.102.109') do
(
echo %ip% 23> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "d0n07en7er\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT ">">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "en\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "d0n07en7er\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "config t\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "int fa0/%faint%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "switchport acc vlan %vlan%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "no sh\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "end\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "q\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT>> swvlandetail.txt
set /P confirm=Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N] or [U] to update you data ? 
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "Y" goto switchvlan
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "N" goto mainmenu
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "U" goto portinfo
)
```

*FOR LOOP ENDS HERE*

```
echo %ip% 23> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Username:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%uname%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%passwd%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT ">">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "en\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%passwd%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "config t\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "int fa0/%faint%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "switchport acc vlan %vlan%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "no sh\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "end\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "q\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT>> swvlandetail.txt
set /P confirm=Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N] or [U] to update you data ? 
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "Y" goto switchvlan
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "N" goto mainmenu
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "U" goto portinfo

:switchvlan
cls
echo Starting ...
Ping.exe localhost -n 2 >NUL
cls
echo.
tst10.exe /r:swvlandetail.txt
echo Returning to Main Menu...
Ping.exe localhost -n 2 >NUL
goto mainmenu
```

the problem is:
there are 2 type of configurations of access switches (CISCO). one type have tacacs running and the other will only prompt for the telnet password which predefined in the running-config of the switch (so that the only the local support could access the access switches). when the user want to configure a switch for the one which only prompt for the telnet password. the telnet programs cant use the temp files (swvlandetail.txt) to send commands to the telnet session. it will hangs because it suppose to wait until the prompt prompted Username: instead of Password:

**Explanation:**
 1. the .bat will help 1st level support (who have zero knowledge on CISCO) to:
 - switch vlan on a desired FastEthernet Port (e.g.: Fa0/13) or
 - restart a desired FastEthernet Port or
 - disable a desired FastEthernet Port

1. if the Switch to be configure is not using cisco tacacs service (e.g: 10.195.30.5 or 10.195.102.42) below command should be running:

*code should be running:*

```
echo %ip% 23> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "d0n07en7er\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT ">">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "en\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "d0n07en7er\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "config t\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "int fa0/%faint%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "switchport acc vlan %vlan%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "no sh\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "end\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "q\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT>> swvlandetail.txt
set /P confirm=Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N] or [U] to update you data ? 
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "Y" goto switchvlan
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "N" goto mainmenu
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "U" goto portinfo
```

*this will create swvlandetail.txt as shown below*

```
10.195.30.5 23
WAIT "Password:\m"
SEND "d0n07en7er\m"
WAIT ">"
SEND "en\m"
WAIT "Password:"
SEND "d0n07en7er\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "config t\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "int fa0/13\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "switchport acc vlan 82\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "no sh\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "end\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "q\m"
WAIT
```

1. if the switch to be configured is a normal switch which running tacacs for authentication. below command should run:

*code should be running:*

```
echo %ip% 23> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Username:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%uname%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%passwd%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT ">">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "en\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "Password:">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "%passwd%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "config t\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "int fa0/%faint%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "switchport acc vlan %vlan%\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "no sh\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "end\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT "#">> swvlandetail.txt
echo SEND "q\m">> swvlandetail.txt
echo WAIT>> swvlandetail.txt
set /P confirm=Are you sure you want to continue[Y/N] or [U] to update you data ? 
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "Y" goto switchvlan
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "N" goto mainmenu
if /I "%confirm%" EQU "U" goto portinfo
```

*which will be creating another looks of swvlandetail.txt like below:*

```
10.195.102.100 23
WAIT "Username:"
SEND "aaasaud\m"
WAIT "Password:"
SEND "n3ssus_m4n1\m"
WAIT ">"
SEND "en\m"
WAIT "Password:"
SEND "n3ssus_m4n1\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "config t\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "int fa0/15\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "switchport acc vlan 89\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "no sh\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "end\m"
WAIT "#"
SEND "q\m"
WAIT
```

*there will be another program which will starts the telnet session and inputing all in the swvlandetail.txt to that telnet.exe*
**The portion which will starts the telnet.exe is below:**

```
:switchvlan
cls
echo Starting ...
Ping.exe localhost -n 2 >NUL
cls
echo.
tst10.exe /r:swvlandetail.txt
echo Returning to Main Menu...
Ping.exe localhost -n 2 >NUL
goto mainmenu
```

Comment: Can you be more specific; What is the problem you're having, do you know what part of this isn't working, what is the expected result / what is the result you are getting?

Comment: the problem is:
there are 2 type of configurations of access switches (CISCO). one type have tacacs running and the other will only prompt for the telnet password which predefined in the running-config of the switch (so that the only the local support could access the access switches). when the user want to configure a switch for the one which only prompt for the telnet password. the telnet programs cant use the temp files (swvlandetail.txt) to send commands to the telnet session. it will hangs because it suppose to wait until the prompt prompted Username: instead of Password:

Comment: the problem is the for loop ive created. when it prompt to continue it just close the terminal and nothing happens.

Comment: with `(` on a line by itself, it must be after the `do` keyword as in " do (" without the quotes.

Comment: A tip here: I suggest that you remove all the Telnet scripts from your question, they are not relevant to the batch file (or are the telnet scripts failing?) and are making the code very long.  People will avoid reading long questions with a lot of code.

Answer (score 1):

Excuse me. This is one of those questions that have too much information, but does not clearly explain the point. I extracted these phrases from your question:

- "if the ip being input by the user matching in the predefined list it will carry some commands and if the user input is not match it will run another set of command"
- if the user input the ip that matching the one in the list i would like the program to continue to create temp files (swvlandetail.txt)"

This code segment achieve that selection:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set predefinedList=/10.195.30.5/10.195.102.42/10.195.102.109/

set /p ip=Access Switch IP : 
if "!predefinedList:/%ip%/=!" neq "%predefinedList%" (
   rem The given ip IS in the list:
   rem Continue create the temp files
   rem and carry some commands
) else (
   rem Run another set of command
)
```

If this is not what you want, please explain it clearly...

Comment: it looks like your code is the missing puzzle. it fits my whole coding and served it purpose. thanks mate... finally; a good nite sleep for me... just for xtra info, could i predefine the ip list in a .txt ? so that it will be a single point of entry for any switch update / added into the local lan...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with your for loop. You cannot use the %ip% variable in your for loop here - `for %ip% in ('10.195.30.5' '10.195.102.42') do`

The correct syntax would be `for %%A in (10.195.30.5 10.195.102.42) do` then you can set `ip` to `%%A`.

However you seem to be trying to use the variable `ip` twice, why are you setting it here - `set /p ip=Access Switch IP :` - but then looping through two completely separate ip addresses?

If the double assignment of the `ip` variable is accidental then you can just change the initial declaration of the access switch ip address to something like `AccessIP`.

Comment: first i need the user to input the ip address of the switch, then i want to check whether that the ip is the switch with no tacacs running. if the user input the ip that matching the one in the list i would like the program to continue to create temp files (swvlandetail.txt) with command outside the for loop (which i predefined the password to use to telnet)

Comment: @Aacini answer is definitely the best.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of code with many errors here, but not much detail on what is required. You appear to be assuming that everyone is familiar with what the commands you want to issue **SHOULD** be.

First matter is that a `FOR` loop's metavariable may only be a single letter. The general syntax is

```
for %%x in (list of items) do command
```

so where you have `%ip%` in your `FOR` loop, you need to substitute `%%x` (`x` can be any letter you like, but **IS** case-sensitive)

Next, the items in the list are taken **LITERALLY** so if you `'quote'` then the item substituted for the metavariable will be `'quoted'`. We have no information about whether or not this is correct.

Next, in a compound statement, the opening parenthesis **MUST** be on the same physical line as the `DO`.

```
for %%x in (item1 item2) do (
 echo %%x
 echo I repeat - %%x
)
```

We have no idea of where `%vlan%` and `%faint%` come from. Batch will substitute the variable's value for any `%variable%` within the loop - **BUT** the value substituted will be the value the variable had **AT THE TIME THE `FOR` LOOP WAS PARSED** - not as it is changed by the operation of the loop. That applies to `%confirm%` too - the value is set when the `FOR` loop is started. (see any number of posts here on SO about `DELAYED EXPANSION` for methods to get around this)

Next issue is that `echo ...> filename` will RESTART the file on each loop, so its contents on exit will be that set up by the last iteration.

And really, no idea what `\m` means to you. The text will be reproduced in the target textfile exactly as <kbd>\</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> - it will not be translated to a control-character, if that is what you expected.

Comment: it coming from : set /p faint=Interface : Fa0/ and set /p vlan=Vlan to switch to : this is from user input.